# Exception django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet

Tags: django, django-settings

I have upgraded django version from 1.8 into 1.9 and django rest framework to 3.3.3. I am getting this exception:
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

I have tried as follows but exception is still there.

```
#__init__.py
default_app_config = 'panel.apps.PanelConfig'
```

And also

```
#apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig

class PanelConfig(AppConfig):
    name    = 'panel'

    def ready(self):
        from panel import receivers
```

for all apps and added these to installed apps

```
'api.apps.ApiConfig',
'billing.apps.ApiConfig',
'incoming.apps.IncomingConfig',
'outgoing.apps.OutgoingConfig',
'panel.apps.PanelConfig',
```

This is my full traceback:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7f3eec09c7d0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sparrow/virtualenvs/bishnu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sparrow/virtualenvs/bishnu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/sparrow/virtualenvs/bishnu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/home/sparrow/virtualenvs/bishnu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sparrow/virtualenvs/bishnu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/sparrow/virtualenvs/bishnu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/sparrow/virtualenvs/bishnu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/sparrow/virtualenvs/bishnu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/admin_tools/dashboard/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from admin_tools.dashboard.dashboards import *
  File "/home/sparrow/virtualenvs/bishnu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/admin_tools/dashboard/dashboards.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
  File "/home/sparrow/virtualenvs/bishnu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 161, in <module>
    class ContentType(models.Model):
  File "/home/sparrow/virtualenvs/bishnu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 94, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/home/sparrow/virtualenvs/bishnu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 239, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/home/sparrow/virtualenvs/bishnu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Exception is still there ? What is the problem ? I am not getting ?

Comment: The full traceback might show you the import which is causing the problem.

Comment: I just googled the error and it came up with several StackOverflow pages with a few ideas that people say worked for them. Not going to reproduce them all here but is sounds like this error is not actually very descriptive of the root cause.

Comment: I have edited question with full traceback, can u help further ?

Answer (score 0):

The traceback shows you that the problem is occuring in [admin_tools](http://django-admin-tools.readthedocs.io/).

```
    from admin_tools.dashboard.dashboards import *
  File "/home/sparrow/virtualenvs/bishnu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/admin_tools/dashboard/dashboards.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
```

It looks like [it has been fixed](https://github.com/django-admin-tools/django-admin-tools/commit/9470008dd29db6c3cef2177839a57cdf371d21e5), so try upgrading to the latest release, currently 0.7.2.